# Central Administration has an option to enable RSS feeds

Tags: rss

Central Administration has an option to enable RSS feeds. After enabling that, what methods or events are available for us to use, and where do we use them in order to connect to an RSS feed?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RSS Settings` in Central Administration are accessible via API using [SPWebApplication.SyndicationEnabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spwebapplication.syndicationenabled%28v=office.12%29.aspx) property.

In turn this affect on the following settings :

- Site Rss Settings (*Site Settings -> Site Administration -> RSS*), see  [SPSite.AllowRssFeeds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsite.allowrssfeeds.aspx) property for more details
- List Rss Settings (*Library Settings -> Communication*)
- Rss Feed Settings for [Content Query web part](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.webcontrols.contentbyquerywebpart.aspx)